# python for loop logic to check variables against

Tags: python-2.7

I quite new to python and I am struggling with the logic of how to loop through the below problem. So, I have a simple list, which is like so:

```
cat_list = [
            ["cambridge university", "cricket", "cu c url name"],
            ["cambridge university", "football", "cu f url name"],
            ["cambridge university", "golf", "cu g url name"],
            ["cambridge university", "default", "cu d url name"],
            ["oxford university", "cricket", "ou c url name"],
            ["oxford university", "football", "ou f url name"],
            ["oxford university", "golf", "ou g url name"],
            ["oxford university", "default", "ou d url name"],
            ["hertford university", "default", "hu d url name"],
           ]
```

and then, I have two strings `x` and `y` holding:

```
x = "cambridge university"
y = "nfl" # this can change
```

Now, I would like to check (using a for loop) if `x` and `y` matches a row of `cat_list` and if it does, I would like to print the corresponding url value (third column of cat_list). Further, if it cannot find `y` in cat_list (but finds `x`), I would like to go to its corresponding `default` value and print out again the corresponding url value in cat_list.

So, with the `x` and `y` above, I would like the for loop to output `cu d url name`.

However, if `x` and `y` were say,

```
x = "oxford university"
y = "cricket"
```

then Id like the for loop to output `ou c url name`.

Sorry if this is a 101 question - think I am just severely confused :(

*EDIT*

So, obviously, one could run a simple loop as described by qwwqwwq:

```
for item in cat_list:
    if item[0] == x and item[1] == y:
        print item[2]
for item in cat_list:
    if item[0] == x and item[1] == 'default':
        print item[2]
```

but, with `x = "oxford university" y = "cricket"` both the above `if` would be satified - which is not what I want. The "default" value should ONLY be printed in case the sport(`y`) is not found for the corresponding `x`

Comment: +1 for a detailed explanation of what you want to achieve, but -1 for lack of demonstration of attempts to resolve this yourself

Comment: you could try using python dictionaries. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answers have suggested, you can do a simple loop over your list to see if there's a matching value. Handling the default value is a bit more complicated, but you can save if you see it as you go through the list, then print it if you reach the end of the loop.

```
default = None
for university, sport, url_name in cat_list:
    if university == x:
        if sport == y:
            print url_name
            break # stop looping
        elif sport == 'default':
            default = url_name
else: # triggered only if the loop reached the end without hitting a break statement
    print default
```

If you're going to be querying the same list many times though, you can use a dictionary instead to get better performance. Here's how you can create the dictionary from your current list:

```
cat_dict = {(university, sport): url_name for (university, sport, url_name) in cat_list}
```

To query it for a given `x` and `y`:

```
if (x, y) in cat_dict:
    print cat_dict[x, y]
else:
    print cat_dict[x, 'default']
```

This version takes `O(1)` (constant) time for each query on average, while the loop above is `O(N)`.

Comment: @Blcknght: thanks so much for this detailed answer! It certainly works now! Accepted your answer. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

With the data structure as is you need to loop through twice, if you don't find x and y matching on the first try, then look for the default value, if you don't find a default value, maybe raise an exception..

```
def get_url(x,y,cat_list):
    for item in cat_list:
        if item[0] == x and item[1] == y:
            return item[2]
    for item in cat_list:
        if item[0] == x and item[1] == 'default':
            return item[2]
    raise Exception("No default url found  for {university}".format(university = x))
```

Comment: thanks for this - but I have a small problem with this - what happens now with your code is that both the `if` loops get satisfied (say `x="oxford university"` and `y="cricket"`). What I'd want is if the `x` and `y` are satisfied to print the corresponding URL value and `NOT` its default value which it would with your code. Am I making sense here? :(

Comment: @JamesW: This code will work fine. If an exact match is found in the first loop, the `return` statement will end its execution immediately, so you won't return the default from the second list. One possible improvement might be to save the default value when it is seen in the first loop, so that you don't need to loop twice (just have two tests in the single pass). It won't be a big improvement though (still `O(N)`).

Comment: @Blckknght: Am I right in saying that this would only work if it is a function and not if the for loops are standalone as I have posted on the edit section. The problem is, I am doing this on a django template, so I cannot have any `functions` as such :(

Comment: Oh I see, you are trying to do all of this within the django templating language? Ideally then you should have an object that can respond to __getitem__ or __getattr__ to return the appropriate value given x and y, something like what blckknght has shown, then you just pass that object to render your template and life is good!